# Is it Possible to get the multiple set result into single set of result in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [CONTENTS].[ID] 
(
    [ID]        NVARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [NAME]      NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [CONTENT]   NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [PARENT_ID] NVARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [TYPE]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [SHARED]    INT             NOT NULL,
    [CREATED]   DATETIME        NULL,
    [ICON]      VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    [UPDATED]   DATETIME        NULL
);
```

Every item has the parent item except some major items. I need to get for required item Parent, Parent of Parent, until the item having no parent..

I used the following query

```
DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max)='12843686753443770653';

WAY:
SET @ID = (SELECT PARENT_ID FROM CONTENTS.ID WHERE (ID = @ID))

SELECT * 
FROM CONTENTS.ID 
WHERE (ID = @ID)

IF @ID!='JKParthiban' GOTO WAY
```

I got this result:

[image]

I need all the results in a single set instead of multiple sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive cte to get the results

```
DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max)='12843686753443770653';
;with cte as (
select id, name from contentsid where id = @ID

union all

select ci.ID, ci.name from cte c inner join contentsid ci
on c.id = ci.PARENT_ID
) select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Union All is the most common way to do this......  You can merge completely different queries into one this way.  I frequently merge dis-similar data when feeding Crystal Reports that wants a single data set.  I add a column for data type to identify which of the different merged queries the data relates to.

Comment: Hi @M T Head, Union All gives the proper result which mentioned by Kannan

Comment: I was agreeing with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

From @Kannan answer I have made small change. It gives my required result

```
DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max)='20702008786843307405';
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT ID, NAME,PARENT_ID from CONTENTS.ID where ID = @ID UNION ALL SELECT CI.ID, CI.NAME, CI.PARENT_ID from CTE C inner join CONTENTS.ID CI 
ON C.PARENT_ID = CI.ID) SELECT * FROM CTE
```